# Pandas countif with condition

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I have a data set in pandas with a unique event key, a person key, a date, and other various columns. I am trying to add a new column that would give the count of events for the person prior to the date on that row. I keep searching but I am only finding results for set criteria (i.e. df ['x']=df [df ['date']<'2018-06-01'] where the date does not dybamically change with each row) or for a .apply (function) method which takes a long time.

I am thinking about putting the df into an sqlite db and then joining the table to itself and then a count distinct case statement. Example below. However, there are additional manipulations I need to do subsequently and I assume there has to be a quicker way to do this in python. Any suggestions?

```
Sample data in df- dates repeat and not in order. Multiple people can be on one date and a person can have multiple events on a single date.
[Event, person, date]
[1,1,2018-01-03]
[2,1,2018-01-01]
[3,1,2018-01-02]
[4,2,2018-01-04]
[5,2,2018-01-05]

Desired output

[Event, person, date, count of evnt]
[1,1,2018-01-03,    2]
[2,1,2018-01-01,    0]
[3,1,2018-01-02,    1]
[4,2,2018-01-04,    0]
[5,2,2018-01-05,    1]
```

Sorry for the format, I am on my phone.

Example:

Say the fields are evebt, person, date I would

```
Select event, 
             person, 
             date,  
             Count (distinct (case when ((t2.date less than
t1.date) And (t2.person=t1.person))
 Then t2.event else null end)) event_count

From t1

Left outer join t1 as t2 on (t2.event=t1.event)

Group by event, person, date.
```

Comment: I cant fully get what you are trying to do? Could you clarify it a bit more and perhaps show some of your python code?

Comment: Can you give an example of the input? From your description, I would try groupby person, sort by date, and then count.